# How to get a list of all folder names inside a folder in cpanel?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I would like to get the names of all folders inside a folder in Cpanel. In my wordpress website, I need to get all the folder names (names of plugins) in public_html/wp-content/plugins to be saved into a text file which is located inside the root folder. How do I achieve this?

I tried with the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$files = scandir($dir,0);
 foreach ($files as $value) {
      if ($value > "0" && is_file($value)){
      print $value . "\n";}}

    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pluginlist.txt"');
    readfile($value);
exit;
?>
```

I saved this file as "pluginlist.php" inside /wp-content/plugins.

Comment: `opendir` , `scandir` functions?

Comment: yes, but I don't have a clear idea.

Comment: You said _names of all sub folders inside a folder in Cpanel_ . So, you want to recursively iterate subfolders as well?

Comment: No, I mean folders inside the plugins folder. I will edit the question.

Comment: If you want to create a WordPress plugin you need few more lines of code in order to make it work. Official guide is a good place to start: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: ```@Maciek Rek``` OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently printing values and then adding headers. It needs to be the other way round. Also, you are checking for `is_file()` but should rather be [`is_dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) check.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pluginlist.txt"');


foreach (array_diff(scandir(__DIR__),array(".","..")) as $value) {
    if (is_dir($value)){
        echo $value . "\n";
    }
}

exit;
```

Comment: @Ajesh Glad to help